# IDisposable within Constructor Chain

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I have the following two constructors:

```cs
public Source(FileStream fileStream) {
    // Stuff
}

public Source(String fileName) : this(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)) {
    // Nothing, the other constructor does the work
}
```

The issue with the second constructor is rather obvious, a FileStream is being created and used, but not disposed. Because it's inside of a constructor chain, a `using` block is not possible. I can't move the `new FileStream()` into the body of the constructor because, while it would then be in a `using` block, the logic of the other constructor wouldn't be able to be called. I can't extract out that logic because it modifies `readonly` fields. I *could* duplicate the logic in each constructor, but that's obviously not a good solution.

I really would prefer to keep the syntactic sugar the second constructor provides. How can I best do this? Or is this just a bad idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `StreamReader` implementation, which has two types of ctors:

```
public StreamReader(Stream stream)
      : this(stream, true)
    {
    }

public StreamReader(string path)
      : this(path, true)
    {
    }
```

Internally they both call the same `Init` method with a parameter `leaveOpen`, which is set to `true` for the first ctor and to `false` for the second ctor and based on this parameter the `Stream` gets (or not) disposed.

So you can do something like this:

```
public class Source : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Stream _stream;
    private readonly bool _leaveOpen;

    private Source(Stream stream, bool leaveOpen)
    {
        _stream = stream;
        _leaveOpen = leaveOpen;
    }

    public Source(FileStream fileStream) : this(fileStream, true)
    {

    }

    public Source(string fileName) : this(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open), false)
    {

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_leaveOpen)
        {
            _stream?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While correct that's way more complicated for what I think OP wants (as they don't seem to need to access file past constructors)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really sure what's stopping you disposing of it in the constructor that takes the `FileStream`:

```
public Source(FileStream fileStream) {
    try
    {
        // Stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        fileStream.Dispose();
    }
}

public Source(String fileName) : this(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)) {
    // Nothing, the other constructor does the work
}
```

If it's because you want to keep the `Stream` alive for callers of the `FileStream` constructor, you can add a third `private` constructor:

```
public Source(FileStream fileStream): this(fileStream, disposeStream: false) {
    // Nothing, the other constructor does the work
}

public Source(String fileName) : this(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open), disposeStream: true) {
    // Nothing, the other constructor does the work
}

private Source(FileStream fileStream, bool disposeStream) {
    try
    {
        // Stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        if (disposeStream)
        {
            fileStream.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/IDisposableAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/IDISP007.md

I'm writing a library meant for third party consumption. Disposing someones object is absolutely a horrible thing to do. The lifetime of the object is something they need to manage, not me for them. This is a well known issue you're advocating for.

Comment: @Patrick I'm not sure I follow - doesn't my second proposed solution handle that? It disposes of your own object but not theirs. I don't really see how I'm advocating for it.